# Problem creating JSON data in asynchronous loop with Vuejs and FileReader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I have a vue form component for which user can submit multiple files. I need to process these files before submitting data to a remote API that takes JSON data.

I have tried to solve this using FileReader and asynchronous foreach loop as follows:

```js
methods: {
  readerLoaded(geojson, date, post_data) {
    post_data.dated_profiles.push({
                  'date': date,
                  'geojson': geojson
                });
  },
  setupReader(file, date, post_data, readerLoaded) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      const result = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
      // Send result to callback
      readerLoaded(result, date, post_data);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  },
  validate() {
    if ( this.$refs.form.validate() ) {
      /* Process GeoJSON files to POST data to API */
      const data = {
          'name': this.name,
          'index': this.index,
          'dated_profiles': Array()
      }

      const asyncLoopFunction = async (datasets, post_data, setupReader, readerLoaded) => {
        const promises = datasets.map(function (item) { return setupReader(item.file, item.date, post_data, readerLoaded); })
        return await Promise.all(promises)
      }

      asyncLoopFunction(this.datasets, data, this.setupReader, this.readerLoaded).then( () => {
        console.log('All async tasks complete!')
        console.log("After async", data)
        this.$store.dispatch('postProfile', data)
      });

    }
  }
```

Problem is: when I pass my final JSON data object to Vuex store action (using `dispatch`), my `dated_profiles` array is empty.

- If I check the JSON object after the async loop is done, browser console displays this `Object { name: "foo", index: "1", dated_profiles: [] }`. Array looks empty but when I expand it, I can see the correct full array…
- If I pass this data to the request, it tells me my array is definitely empty. Shouldn't it be waiting for all the promises to finish ?

I don't understand why my async/await combination is not working, where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `this.setup_reader` to the `asyncLoopFunction`. I believe it should be `this.setupReader`.

Also, your `setupReader` method is not currently returning a promise. You should change it to:

```
setupReader(file, date, post_data, readerLoaded) {
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      const result = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
      readerLoaded(result, date, post_data);
      resolve();
    };
    reader.onerror = () => reject();
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
},
```

Comment: As for the function name, it is a mistake in my post, I've updated it ! Thanks for your anwser, I guess I didn't understand how FileReader / async loop with promises work. Please tell me if I'm wrong: as setupReader was returning nothing, the await was useless and everything finished before my array was populated, right ?

Comment: Nope. The `async` was not useless. But if you don't feed promises to a `Promise.all()`  array, it's going to resolve as soon as the function executes (sync). For example, now, that they are promises, if you remove the `async` it won't work. You need it.